# How to compile in multiple platform a CGProgram in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cg

When I tried building my works from unity to phone, the shining effect only working on editor but not on the build?

> How can I resolve this one? I've heard about compilation of shaders but it confuse me more.

Answer (score 0):

## Preamble

What you've heard is irrelevant in Unity's world. Unity takes care of compiling shaders by itself.

## Solving the problem

First thing to do is to switch Unity's platform to either iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone or whatever:

```
File → Build Settings... → Choose your mobile platform → Click "Switch Platform" button.
```

Then you need to turn on graphics emulation:

```
Edit → Graphics Emulation → OpenGL ES
```

While this is not a 100% accurate emulation, it will help you to catch some problems. For the rest read what Xcode output tells you.

Comment: I already do this one but nothing happened. The one that I applied on shader will just gone to pink instead of the shine effect. Do I need to add Shader in AssetBundle?

Comment: You already do what? Does Xcode output tell you something about shaders?

Comment: I tried the solution you gave about in unity and run through x-code. But it will give NullException for Google Ads instead and can't continue to the game. I need to fix maybe this one first before I can continue to build in Xcode. How about if I will try to build in Android? can it give me an error after I build in Android platform?

Comment: If your app is not working at all, how can you tell that your shader is not working?

Comment: I build it on Android device and also in iPad(which is a failure). but in Android, I put the shader on my win prefab and I have ShineShader. In Unity its perfectly fine but when I build in Android device it the shader that I add on the sprite will become pink. I dont know why. Is there any additional script that I will add in order for it to work in Android devices? Sorry taking your time and thank you for your reply.

Comment: If it becomes pink it means that the problem is in the shader. Xcode should tell you something about it. But to tell you the truth, from what I see in your comments, I doubt that you are able to fix it. Thus, I would recommend you to include your shader code here so that me or someone else can help you with it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yeah. Its just dumb of me. I forgot to instantiate it. I successfully run after instantiate it to my Shader class and apply it to the Sprite. Thank you very much for your concern.